# Usage of a particular code in bulletin-of-the-ams latex template

Tags: amsart

I'm trying to make a template for writing my personal mathematical notes based on the `amsart` class. I copied this file (https://www.ams.org/arc/journals/packages/bull/bull_amslatex/journal.tex) and was trimming away the things that I might not need (like multiple authors etc). I found this code in the preamble:

```
%    Blank box placeholder for figures (to avoid requiring any
%    particular graphics capabilities for printing this document).
\newcommand{\blankbox}[2]{%
  \parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering
%    Set fboxsep to 0 so that the actual size of the box will match the
%    given measurements more closely.
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \fbox{\raisebox{0pt}[#2]{\hspace{#1}}}%
  }%
}
```

I am wondering if I should delete it or not. What is the purpose of this code, and is it okay to delete it? I found no difference in the output by excluding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `journal.tex` this command is used twice, on lines 258-267:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\blankbox{.6\columnwidth}{5pc}
\caption{This is an example of a figure caption with text.}
\label{firstfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\blankbox{.75\columnwidth}{3pc}
\caption{}\label{otherfig}
\end{figure}
```

As you can see this command serves to illustrate how figures are used in this template, without actually showing a figure. Instead a 'blank box' is shown with the dimensions given by the arguments of the command.

So you can safely delete the code, unless you want to use a similar image placeholder when you pass your template on to other people, for example. However, in that case you can also use the `demo` or `draft` options for the `graphicx` package, or use `\includegraphics{example-image}`, which will include the file `example-image.png` that is part of the `mwe` package that comes with most LaTeX distributions by default.